# Jasmine tests in Angular 9 - dependency injection errors

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

I have recently decided to update my ionic project from 4 to 5, and figured while i was at it i would update from Angular 8 to 9.

All went well and the app works as expected until i tried to run my unit tests.  I am bombarded with this error and I can't figure out why.  I suspect it has to do with the Router, but i can't even confirm that.

```
Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.
Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.
    at Module.ɵɵinvalidFactory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:14150:1)
    at Object.Router_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/router.js:4404:67)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:11425:1)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:11247:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:787:1)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:792:1)
    at Function.NavController_Factory [as ɵfac] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@ionic/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/ionic-angular.js:798:205)
    at Object.factory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@ionic/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/ionic-angular.js:799:96)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js:11425:1)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.
```

Any ideas or anyone else come across this?

EDIT

Here is what one of the failing tests looks like

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ZoneInstructionsComponent } from './zone-instructions.component';
import { LocationStrategy, Location, PathLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { UrlSerializer, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

describe('ZoneInstructionsComponent', () => {
  let component: ZoneInstructionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ZoneInstructionsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ZoneInstructionsComponent ],
      imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot() ],
      providers: [
        Location,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/page' },
        UrlSerializer,
        { provide: Router, userClass: RouterModule },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ZoneInstructionsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Pretty basic, not even really testing anything

EDIT 2

Here is the component code, nothing to do it

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'stm-zone-instructions',
  templateUrl: './zone-instructions.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../installation-wizard.page.scss',
    './zone-instructions.component.scss'
  ]
})
export class ZoneInstructionsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Any way to narrow it down to a specific test and post the code here?

Comment: @Phix I have updated the original post.. thanks

Comment: @AndySousa : Are you running test case for `ZoneInstructionsComponent` using `fdescribe`  ? if soo, can u please provide the component code as well

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have added the component code.  Its basically a stub... nothing to it.  I wasn't running it with fdescribe, but i just did with the same result for that single test

Answer (score 2):

well it was just plain stupid on my part... lots of places I was using

```
{ provide: Router, userClass: RouterModule },
```

and apparently Angular 9 is saying no no to that.  Updating my specs to use the RouterTestingModule and all good now.  Surprised it took this long to catch this.  I would love to know why exactly, I have a lot to learn with jasmine tests still.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ZoneInstructionsComponent } from './zone-instructions.component';
import { LocationStrategy, Location, PathLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('ZoneInstructionsComponent', () => {
  let component: ZoneInstructionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ZoneInstructionsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ZoneInstructionsComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), IonicModule.forRoot() ],
      providers: [
        Location,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/page' }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ZoneInstructionsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice catch. In case you want to explore more on Unit testing, I hope https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 might help you. I have written series of articles which I found missing over internet